# How to provide MockService in development with Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a class `MailService` and a class `MailMockService` which should be used in development.

According to the [Nest documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#use-class), it should work like this:

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: MailService,
      useClass: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') ? MailMockService : MailService,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

However, it does not work as expected. `process.env.NODE_ENV` is equal to `'development'` but the module still provides the class `MailService`.

How can I make the module to provide `MailMockService` depending on the environment?

**Edit:**

I use the service like this:

```
import { MailService } from './mail/mail.service';
...
const mailService = new MailService();
```

I think, the `import`  bypasses the provided `MailService`/`MailMockService` from the `Module` (The code still works without the object in the `providers` array). But how can I tell the program to use the `MailMockService`?

Comment: It also doesn't work if you replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` by `true`? Have you provided the `MailService` multiple times?

Comment: @KimKern Please see my edited question.

Comment: The `MailService` has to be created by the framework not in your code, see my answer. Where are you using the `MailService` and is there a reason why you didn't inject it?

Comment: Im curious as to why you would want to use a different service between production and dev. In any case, couldn't you just do something like: const mailerSvc = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV' 
    ? require('path/to/mock')
    : require('path/to/real/thing')

Comment: @Pytth I implemented it just like that but a) it seems wrong to me to have the mockservice within the controller and b) I'm curious how `@Module` works in detail :)

Comment: @MauriceWipf Still not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you create an instance of the service yourself instead of using nest's dependency injection, you're defeating the purpose of the framework.

> But how can I tell the program to use the `MailMockService`?

This is exactly what makes dependency injection so great: You can control the dependencies that are used in your units (classes, modules,...) without changing those units themselves. Great for testing or environment-specifics, like in your case.

So the class that uses the `MailService` has to be created by the framework and can then inject the `MailService` with:

```
constructor(private mailService: MailService) {}
```

Then the instance will be used that is provided in your `providers` array.

---

If this is not possible, you can of course have the logic in the consuming class(es) itself (not very nice!):

```
const mailService = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' 
                    ? new MailMockService()
                    : new MailService();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```js
const mailerSvc = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV' 
    ? require('path/to/mock')
    : require('path/to/real/thing')
```